# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN only for Chrome

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, dns, windows-10

I can't access to the internet with Chrome and I have this error : `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` but only for Chrome (44.0.2403.130 m (64-bit)). I can access to all my websites with Edge.
I've already restarted my PC, changed the DNS server and reinstalled and cleared Google Chrome cache but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried an elevated command prompt with:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```